# Wifimanager how to connect to WEP/WAP network

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm trying to develop a very simple wifi manager, where you see the available networks list, you select one, put in a password and connect to it.

So far I can get the networks list and info about each network from the `ScanResult` object 
At this point I should implement the connection, UI is on place, but I can't get to connect to the selected network

I understand a wificonfiguration must be set, and via `ScanResult.capabilities` I can get the type of the network (`[WEP],[WPA-PSK-TKIP],[WPA2-PSK-CCMP-preauth]`) and set the `AuthAlgorithm`, the `KeyMgmt` and the `GroupCipher`; then I need to...

```
WifiManager.disconnect();
WifiManager.enableNetwork(id,true);
WifiManager.reconnect();
```

I do something wrong tho, because nothing happens. Well, the wifi does get restarted, but it doesn't connect.

What's the correct way to perform a connection? Is there any way to track whether something went wrong or if the connection succeeded?

EDIT:
 I keep getting a `-1` value on `WifiManager.addNetwork()` apparently... I set up pretty much everything in `WifiManagerConfiguration`, I've no idea what may be the problem, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the correct way to perform a connection?

Your method now seems close. You need to call

```
addNetwork (WifiConfiguration config)
```

This will add a configured network, which is disabled by default. Then call

```
enableNetwork (int netId, boolean disableOthers)
```

> Is there any way to track whether something went wrong or if the connection succeeded?

You can easily find out if the connection succeeded, reconnect() will return true.

this is all untested, obtained by looking at the official Android reference documentation.

You should start [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#reconnect%28%29).

Comment: yea it's pretty much where I've been digging for the last days, I didn't notice I could use 'reconnect()' to check if it succeeded, thx!

I keep getting a -1 value on 'addNetwork()' apparently...
I set up pretty much everything in WifiManagerConfiguration, I've no idea what may be the problem, any idea?